# How to build OpenSSL 1.1.0d for Android

Tags: android, openssl

The OpenSSL documentation and the OpenSSL wiki appear to have instructions for the "old" way to build for Android, but not the "new" way.  Are there instructions somewhere and I just didn't see them?

Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear to me what the "old" and "new" instructions are. Can you add links to the documentation you are using?

Comment: The build system was changed between 1.0.x and 1.1.x but the docs on both sites only refer to the old build method.

Comment: One example of apparently outdated instructions on how to build the Android version of OpenSSL:  https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

Comment: This one doesn't help at all. Just refers to the other.  https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Android

Comment: Perhaps you should state the procedure you used, and the problem or error you encountered.

Comment: The instructions at the link above appear to be for an older version of OpenSSL and therefore wouldn't apply.  I can find no other build instructions anywhere else.

Comment: When I try the build instructions at the above Wiki, the ". ./Setenv-android.sh" command fails.  The output is ": command not found" ten times followed by "bash: ./Setenv-android.sh: line 107: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'ash: ./Setenv-android.sh: line 107: `do".

Comment: Ok, finally figured that out. Wasn't remotely obvious but needed to run dos2unix on Setenv-android.sh...

Comment: Now it's failing on the 'build all' step.  i get a bunch of "mv -f" commands followed by some configuration-looking stuff, followed by a bunch of linker errors of this variety: "arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./libcrypto.a(aes_cbc.o): incompatible target".

Comment: And a bunch more follow, all the same type of error.  "arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./libcrypto.a(aes_cfb.o): incompatible target
arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./libcrypto.a(aes_core.o): incompatible target
arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./libcrypto.a(aes_ecb.o): incompatible target
"

Comment: I am receiving the "fatal error: assert.h: No such file or directory " for android-ndk-r16 . Tried to compile also 1.0.1.e and the same behaviour

Comment: I'd recommend trying different versions of OpenSSL until one works, though I realize that shouldn't be necessary.  Note that newer versions Xcode and Android NDK will typically cause issues as well, until OpenSSL catches up.